# Process audio to get the original sound at double speed

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

The basic idea is to process the audio so that [a track doubled in time](https://youtu.be/mWDiRd0iFOI) at double speed (pls set x2 speed at yt) should sound the same as [the original track](https://youtu.be/fbey6KShVFY)

I've already tried tools like:

- ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i in.wav -filter:a "atempo=0.5" out.wav`; also played with `aresample` and `asetrate`
- rubberband: `rubberband-r3 -t2 in.wav out.wav`
- audacity: different combinations of pitch and tempo effects.

But it seems that I don't understand something about audio processing and as a result I get distorted audio.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Let us know the steps you tried with the applications you listed.

Comment: @BlindSpots thank you, I've added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, just use `atempo=2.0` instead of `atempo=0.5`. (The multiplier is backwards from the video speed filter.)

Test it out with a fun example - [Super Sonic Racing from the video game Super Smash Bros. Ultimate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aUST-BHPgo):

```bash
$ yt-dlp -f bestaudio 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aUST-BHPgo'
...
$ ffmpeg -i 'Super Sonic Racing - Super Smash Bros. Ultimate [_aUST-BHPgo].webm' -filter:a atempo=2.0 SuperSonicRacingFASTER.webm
```